# Chatty footers in the answers

Tags: discussion

I was going through my activity history and noticed that some of my edits was revised. 
[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20262399/revisions) the revision history of that answer.

I always looked at messages like that as at unnecessary noise and something that isn't really welcomed here. So, is it really accepted on StackOverflow to put such kind of footer notes to your answers?

I'm asking because I still don't have 2K reputation on StackOverflow, and therefor i don't have much experience in editing questions and answers apart from suggesting edits.

Comment: The user in question seems to do this quite often.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I hope you like it here. It's a bit rainy outside, but I hope that doesn't put you off your work. Anything in the content that doesn't answer the question is just noise you have to wade through. I hope that helped, I really like this site. It's nice. The users are all friendly and it's a very useful site. Glad to have spoken to you. Have a nice day.

Comment: It's more than just "hi", he's asking to upvote his answer which is far worse.

Comment: @JonW hi there, the weather is good here. And I always thought the same thing. But without having 2K rep i cannot dive into revision wars with people

Comment: asking for upvote isnt a good idea imho

Comment: Weird, he approved suggested edit removing such thing, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3915511). Maybe he changed his mind by now??

Comment: His answer ending "Happy Coding! Remember to up vote if this answer was helpful ! :)" has 179 up votes, he might be on to something here ;)

Comment: @Stijn you are right. I haven't found that question.

Comment: looks like he is doing in some other  answer too ...

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Most should be gone now, I noticed you did a few too.

Comment: @Stijn a chatty thank message for cleaning those foot notes

Comment: I hate when occasionally browsing other Q&A sites that every user will have a signature set with their equivalent of "Please up vote if this was helpful - if it solved your problem then accept!", glad to see they've been edited out.

Comment: some others are 1[funny one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14773355/1723893) , [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21047677/1723893) , [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15919281/1723893) ,[4 dumb answer(not an ans)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5669451/1723893),[5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3221930/1723893)..... [ok i cant do anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=please+upvote)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, had I seen #1 at the time I'm not sure I'd have been able to resist - as cruel as that is. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18914786/2742805)'s pretty good

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is it really accepted on StackOverflow to put such kind of footer notes to your answers?

No. The ["What kind of behavior is expected of users?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) page says:

> Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.
>   Avoid overt self-promotion.

It is a kind of signature, and ssking to upvote answers is self-promotion, and it doesn't add any value to the answer. So it's just noise that should be removed.

Comment: Nice answer. Would you like me to give you an upvote for this? ;)

Comment: @JonW: This doesn't answer about why one would want to do this. [Take a look at my answer](http://fakepornexamplesitethatdoesntexist.com) and accept it if it answers your question.